# How do I convert an object array into a map array?

Tags: java, arrays, casting, hashmap, type-conversion

I have the following code snippet:

```
//create map array and fill it with 3 dummy maps
Map[] mapArr= new Map[3];
for(int i = 0; i < mapArr.length; i++)
{
    Map map = new HashMap();
    mapArr[i] = map;
}

//now remove the second element (index == 1) from the map array
mapArr = ArrayUtils.removeElement(mapArr, 1);
```

My problem is witht he final line of code, because no matter what I try I get the error

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to Map[]

How do I convert the Object[] returned by removeElement() into a Map[]?

Comment: Why are you creating a array of `Map` in the first place? What is your use casE?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not up to me.  We're using this array in a JSP later on, and for whatever reason it is a requirement for it to be a map array.  I assume it's to keep it consistent with the other arrays in our JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to cast it to "Map[]" ?

```
mapArr = (Map[]) ArrayUtils.removeElement(mapArr, 1);
```

Comment: Doing this gives me the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils`

Comment: Your class loader is missing org.apache.commons.

If you are using maven you have to add it as a dependency, for example :
        `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>`